# Possibly incorrect type returned by 'keyof'

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define a type which will allow only strings to be used ask property keys. But strangely after creating such type and applying on it 'keyof' is not returning only `string` as possible type of the keys but rather `string | number`. Why ? is this a bug or check the example bellow.

So the question is why `keyof` is returning always `string | number` instead only `string`?
How to get the correct type of the keys of StringKeysObject, which in my case is only string?

```
type StringKeysObject = {[key:string]:unknown};

const keys: keyof StringKeysObject = 123; // This should not be allowed since the keys can only be of type string but this is what keyof returns as possible types const keys: string | number
```

Comment: It's explained in the handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html (the bottom note says: "this is because JavaScript object keys are always coerced to a string, so `obj[0]` is always the same as `obj["0"]`")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) instead of the object literal type, like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZwPICMArCAY2CgF4oAlUge3gBMAebBFVAGigFdkBrZHQDuyAHwBuALAAoWSTrI2UflgBcKrHQBmsdmkw4CxMpSgBGAEwBmCVAD0AKllRXbgHqfZAFXDQA5Mg8ALb4EPD+UIjYUELkAIbY2IioyPH4ADbQwHRQoJBQ-mxIaP4AdAAUNpaWAJRQjvayQA)

```ts
type StringKeysObject = Record<string, unknown>;

const key: keyof StringKeysObject = 123; /*
      ^^^
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322) */
```

Comment: Great! This does the job, tnx :)